# Using TF.exe for copy last version in any folder

Tags: batch-file, tfs

I currently have a project back up on TFS. What I would like is to recover the files on the server. I tried with this command:

```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get $/Regie/Dev /recursive %userprofile%\documents\TFS
```

But the problem is that its copy / update in my file of my local project ... What I would like is to retrieve the project on the server to be able to copy it in any folder.

Comment: Can you describe your question more detailed? tf get command get the latest files from path you specified. Do you mean you want to retrieve all the files in TFS but only get the files under "Dev" folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"
```

Will give you the help you need. You probably want something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get $/Regie/Dev /version:T /recursive %userprofile%\documents\TFS
```

You may also want to use /remap. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2012/05/18/tf-get-remap/